# Eight remarkable places

Tags: pattern, knowledge, geography

Something very remarkable connects the following eight geographic places.
What is it?

- Bodaybo (Russia)
- Cape Horn
- Christchurch (New Zealand)
- Cocos Islands
- Ghanzi (Botswana)
- Honolulu
- Punta Peclas (Nicaragua)
- Vigo (Spain)

Comment: Guess: they form a regular octagon on a world map?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is:

> These eight locations (roughly) form the vertices of a cube.

These eight places clearly are very far away from each other.
They actually form four pairs of antipodal points (see for instance 
http://wikimapia.org/15392887/Antipodal-Point-from-Honolulu-Hawaii):

- Honolulu and Ghanzi are antipodal
- Punta Peclas and Cocos Islands are antipodal
- Vigo and Christchurch are antipodal
- Cape Horn and Bodabyo are antipodal

These eight points however do **not** maximize the minimum distance among all sets of eight points on the surface of Earth (which was my first guess).
The maximizing point set would form the corners of a square antiprism with edges of equal length, and would not contain any pair of antipodal points:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCode.html
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareAntiprism.html

Comment: Wow, nice! I was close then.